# ShellToast Notification issue

Tags: notifications, local

I want to send shellToast notification on Windows Phone device with specific time interval. I want to get notification on device active, background and closing mode also.

Comment: Could you provide some code what you have tried?

Comment: I just wrote code in BackgroundWorker class Doworker method for show shellToast notification but is is not working.